Only include records that all rows within a group meet a specific condtion
I want to amend my current query to only display the accounts (all fields) that do not have Keep_Flag = 'N' in the query results.
The query's intent is to identify accounts who met a specific condition in order for them to qualify for additional rate discounts. They have to meet the condition for every single month otherwise they are rejected from discount program (the query will pull the past 12 months from today's date).
Query that creates the monthly qualification as a 'Y' or 'N':
SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
CASE
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
         AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
         AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS Keep_Flag
FROM test;

I have created a fiddle example with dummy data.
In the below screenshot, my expected results would only include Account_ID 1001. Account_ID 1002 would not qualify as it includes results that has a Keep_Flag ='N'.

The results I would like to see with the amended query


You could add an analytic/window function call to get the lowest flag value for each account ID, either in the same level of query by repeating the case expression, or more simply using a CTE or inline view (subquery):
SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date, Keep_Flag,
    MIN(Keep_Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS Min_Keep_Flag
FROM (
    SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
    CASE
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
             AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
             AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS Keep_Flag
    FROM test
)
ORDER BY id;




ID
ACCOUNT_ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE
KEEP_FLAG
MIN_KEEP_FLAG




1
1001
4
20
10-DEC-23
Y
Y


2
1001
4
12
05-JAN-24
Y
Y


3
1001
2
40
25-FEB-24
Y
Y


4
1001
3
25
05-MAR-24
Y
Y


5
1001
1
10
20-APR-24
Y
Y


6
1001
4
12
10-MAY-24
Y
Y


7
1001
2
20
19-JUN-24
Y
Y


8
1001
1
35
25-JUL-24
Y
Y


9
1001
3
14
05-AUG-24
Y
Y


10
1001
1
10
20-SEP-24
Y
Y


11
1001
4
13
10-OCT-24
Y
Y


12
1001
2
33
15-NOV-24
Y
Y


13
1001
3
27
10-DEC-24
Y
Y


14
1002
1
10
10-DEC-23
Y
N


15
1002
4
36
05-JAN-24
N
N


16
1002
2
24
24-FEB-24
Y
N


17
1002
4
26
05-MAR-24
N
N


18
1002
2
22
20-APR-24
Y
N


19
1002
1
30
10-MAY-24
Y
N


20
1002
2
20
19-JUN-24
Y
N


21
1002
1
35
25-JUL-24
Y
N


22
1002
3
14
05-AUG-24
Y
N


23
1002
1
10
20-SEP-24
Y
N


24
1002
4
13
10-OCT-24
Y
N


25
1002
2
23
15-NOV-24
Y
N


26
1002
1
41
10-DEC-24
Y
N



And then filter out all the rows which don't have 'Y' as the lowest flag value, which exclude the accounts with any 'N' flags:
SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date, Keep_Flag
FROM (
    SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date, Keep_Flag,
        MIN(Keep_Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS Min_Keep_Flag
    FROM (
        SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
        CASE
            WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
                 AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
                 AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS Keep_Flag
        FROM test
    )
)
WHERE Min_Keep_Flag = 'Y'
ORDER BY id;




ID
ACCOUNT_ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE
KEEP_FLAG




1
1001
4
20
10-DEC-23
Y


2
1001
4
12
05-JAN-24
Y


3
1001
2
40
25-FEB-24
Y


4
1001
3
25
05-MAR-24
Y


5
1001
1
10
20-APR-24
Y


6
1001
4
12
10-MAY-24
Y


7
1001
2
20
19-JUN-24
Y


8
1001
1
35
25-JUL-24
Y


9
1001
3
14
05-AUG-24
Y


10
1001
1
10
20-SEP-24
Y


11
1001
4
13
10-OCT-24
Y


12
1001
2
33
15-NOV-24
Y


13
1001
3
27
10-DEC-24
Y



Or with CTEs instead of nested inline views:
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
    CASE
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
             AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
             AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS Keep_Flag
    FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date, Keep_Flag,
        MIN(Keep_Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS Min_Keep_Flag
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date, Keep_Flag
FROM cte2
WHERE Min_Keep_Flag = 'Y'
ORDER BY id;




ID
ACCOUNT_ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE
KEEP_FLAG




1
1001
4
20
10-DEC-23
Y


2
1001
4
12
05-JAN-24
Y


3
1001
2
40
25-FEB-24
Y


4
1001
3
25
05-MAR-24
Y


5
1001
1
10
20-APR-24
Y


6
1001
4
12
10-MAY-24
Y


7
1001
2
20
19-JUN-24
Y


8
1001
1
35
25-JUL-24
Y


9
1001
3
14
05-AUG-24
Y


10
1001
1
10
20-SEP-24
Y


11
1001
4
13
10-OCT-24
Y


12
1001
2
33
15-NOV-24
Y


13
1001
3
27
10-DEC-24
Y



fiddle

Yes, this makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

@Brent - glad it makes sense *8-) Also I mentioned CTEs at the start, but I've now added a version using CTEs instead of nested inline views, which may be easier to follow/maintain.

Ah... Yes, the CTE's are easier to follow! Thank you for the update!

Thanks for the fiddle!

So first CTE is the code you provided
valid_accounts CTE filters out the accounts that have keep_flag = 'N' for any month.Condition HAVING COUNT(*) ensures that the count of all records for an account matches the count of records with keep_flag = 'Y'
Once valid accounts are found, its filtered from the original data joining with data from valid_accounts.

Fiddle
WITH monthly_qualification AS (
    SELECT id, account_id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
    CASE
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
             AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
             AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS keep_flag
    FROM test
),
valid_accounts AS (
    SELECT account_id
    FROM monthly_qualification
    GROUP BY account_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN keep_flag = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
SELECT t.id, t.account_id, t.reg_con, t.tagg_reading, t.read_date, t.keep_flag
FROM monthly_qualification t
JOIN valid_accounts qa ON t.account_id = qa.account_id
ORDER BY t.account_id, t.read_date;




ID
ACCOUNT_ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE
KEEP_FLAG




1
1001
4
20
10-DEC-23
Y


2
1001
4
12
05-JAN-24
Y


3
1001
2
40
25-FEB-24
Y


4
1001
3
25
05-MAR-24
Y


5
1001
1
10
20-APR-24
Y


6
1001
4
12
10-MAY-24
Y


7
1001
2
20
19-JUN-24
Y


8
1001
1
35
25-JUL-24
Y


9
1001
3
14
05-AUG-24
Y


10
1001
1
10
20-SEP-24
Y


11
1001
4
13
10-OCT-24
Y


12
1001
2
33
15-NOV-24
Y


13
1001
3
27
10-DEC-24
Y




I liked how you use CTE's as part of the solution. They tend to make a lot of sense to me. I may end up using this in the long run, but for testing the additional min column will help my business partner grasp which ones are being included and excluded in a simple glance. Thank you!
